# How to multiply 2 cells and sum the result?

Tags: excel

I have 2 cells C12 and D23 that I want to multiply and then 2 other cells A12 and E32 which i also want to multiply and the result of those to be summed to a different cell A1.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Please try to do that first and write when you encounter a problem. Here is to start with -> http://www.wikihow.com/Multiply-in-Excel

Answer (score 0):

in `A1` cell write:
`=C12*C23 + A12*E32`